# R - create new vectors based on elements of existing vector

Tags: r

and thanks in advance for your help. I am very new to R and am having some trouble with code that, to me looks like it should work, but isn't. I have a data frame like the one below:

```
studentID   classNumber classRating
   7             1           4
   7             2           4
   7             4           3
   79            1           5
   79            2           3
   116           1           5
   116           2           4
   134           1           5
   134           3           5
   134           4           5
```

And I want it to read like this:

```
Student ID  class1  class2  class3  class4
     7         4       4      NA       3
     79        5       3      NA       NA
     116       5       4      NA       NA
     134       5       NA     5        5
```

I've tried to piece together different things that I've come across and it seemed like the best approach was to create a new data frame and matrix and then populate it from the current data frame. I came up with the broken code below:

```
classRatings = data.frame(matrix(NA,4,5))

for(i in 1:nrow(classDB)){
  #Find ratings by each student
  rowsToReplace = classDB$studentID==classRatings$studentID[i]
  #Make a row for each unique studentID in classRatings
  classDB$studentID[rowsToReplace] = classRatings$studentID[i]
     #for each studentID, find put the given rating for each unique class into
     #it's own vector 
     for(j in classDB$classNumber){
       if(classDB$classNumber==1){classRatings$class1==classDB$classRating}[j]
       if(classDB$classNumber==2){classRatings$class2==classDB$classRating}[j]
       if(classDB$classNumber==3){classRatings$class3==classDB$classRating}[j]
       if(classDB$classNumber==4){classRatings$class4==classDB$classRating}[j]
       if(classDB$classNumber==5){classRatings$class5==classDB$classRating}[j] 
              }
          }
```

I'm getting an error that says:

> the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

and I am beyond my skill level to figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try `dcast(df, studentID~classNumber, value.var='classRating')` from `library(reshape2)`

Comment: You should also read the help file for `ifelse` (vectorized) and understand how it differs from `if (cond) expr1 else expr2` (non-vectorized).

Comment: `reshape` gets you close: `reshape(dat, v.names="classRating", idvar="studentID",timevar="classNumber" , direction="wide")`

Comment: `if` is expecting one true or false to decide whether to do the next statement or not. in `if(classDB$classNumber==1)` you are comparing each element of classNumber to 1 so you will get out a vector of logicals the length of the input vector. `if` is basically pointing out this mistake, and taking the first element to move forward in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **tidyr** package can spread this long table into a wider one:

```
library(tidyr)
spread(classDB,classNumber,classRating,fill=NA)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. This works, but I think I prefer the output from dcast, as recommended by akrun above. Its great that there are so many options.